# Using servlet shepherd has started throwing an unusual error

Tags: contentdocument

Our app generates emails that include links to download PDFs. These just stopped working. The links are of the format

http://companyname.force.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/06813000004hRTAAA2

Instead of the browser initiating the download, as usual, I'm seeing the following displayed in the browser

top.location='https://companyname.secure.force.com/ex/errorduringprocessing.jsp'

Any ideas? Is there perhaps a setting that might have gotten turned off that makes content publicly visible?

**EDIT:**

I just tested. I can put the same PDF document into another Sandbox in exactly the same way and the link to the document for that environment will work so it appears to be some config difference that's causing it. What configs could cause public documents to not be visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the issue. A public group had gotten deleted that was a member of the Library that contained the content. Restoring this fixed things and the content was once again accessible publicly via servlet shepherd.

Comment: can you provide more details about the public group. How can i find it.

Comment: @venky I'm sorry, I can no longer remember, it has been more than 4 years since I worked with Salesforce.